# Why does setting a nulalble DateTime to DateTime.Max cause a pgsql parsing error?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

When I set a **nullable date time** to **DateTime.Max** and save it to a database field of postgres type

> timestamp without time zone

it saves it as

> 10000-01-01 00:00:00

Then when I reload a page that merely reads from this table I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

a) Is DateTime? the correct C# conversion type?
b) What is the best way to set the DateTime value?

I checked the docs here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html and it specifies the max value is 294276 AD... but that's lower than is currently set so it can't be that breaking it. I am using the latest version of NpgSql and entity framework

Many thanks

Comment: "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." which line does this error occur?

Comment: var test = context.Users.ToList()

Comment: And how does your Users look like? Is it an EF generated class?

Comment: Perhaps you can also post your `Users` (or `User`) class. That will be useful. Sometimes the error occurred because of unmatching column data type in the data base with the data type in the class (Model)

Comment: sorry I didnt reply. The column in postgres is "timestamp without time zone" and the C# column is DateTime?

Comment: I have had no issues with any other functionality with users. Just this breakage when they are set to a datetime value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your C# code. According to [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The `DateTime.MaxValue` field represents the largest possible value of
>   `DateTime`, which is *December 31, 9999* in the Gregorian calendar.

Your date value is just above this value, hence the exception.

I would suggest explicitly saving a very large date value in the database, e.g. *December 31, 9999*, in case the date value is not available.

Comment: Can you expand this. Its probably painfully obvious but I'm shattered - December 31, 9999 is way before 294276AD?

Comment: The exception is thrown not because the value cannot be stored in the database, but because the value cannot be cast to a `DateTime` c# variable (because of the DateTime.MaxValue limit). Can't you save a null datetime value as `NULL` in your database?

Comment: But that's what I'm asking. Surely that value is actually less than what postgresql supports (9999 < 294276AD) so it should be accepted and would only cause issues if the db had 294276AD and we wanted to store it to a C# datetime?

Comment: @user2330270 Have you debugged your code? Can you show use the line of code that throws the exception?

Comment: var test = context.Users.ToList() so it's a straight read. It's crazy because I'm sure you're right and if I add a smaller date time it may work but I want to know why when it's within the postgres documented range